# Log-Log Line Fitting

Tags: python, plot, syntax-error, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I want to plot the best fit line for my plot. My plot is log log and been having a lot of trouble using trouble when using other codes as a guide so if anyone could help that'd be great. Here's my graph and the code. I can add in the xdata and ydata if anyone thinks thats the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
This is my current code:
x1 = abs(xdata) 
y1 = ydata 
import numpy as np 
logx1 = np.log(x1) 
logy1 = np.log(y1) 
coeffs = np.polyfit(logx1,logy1,deg=3) 
poly = np.poly1d(coeffs) 
yfit = lambda x1: np.exp(poly(np.log(x1))) 
loglog(x1,yfit(x1)) 
show()
```

I've run this code on a test set of data and the problem is definitely my array. I keep getting this error message:
    ** On entry to DLASCL, parameter number  4 had an illegal value
    ** On entry to DLASCL, parameter number  4 had an illegal value
    ** On entry to DLASCL, parameter number  4 had an illegal value
    ** On entry to DLASCL, parameter number  4 had an illegal value
    ** On entry to DLASCL, parameter number  5 had an illegal value
    ** On entry to DLASCL, parameter number  4 had an illegal value

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend to add your current code and specify the problem.

Comment: This is my current code:x1 = abs(xdata)
y1 = ydata
import numpy as np
logx1 = np.log(x1)
logy1 = np.log(y1)
coeffs = np.polyfit(logx1,logy1,deg=3)
poly = np.poly1d(coeffs)

yfit = lambda x1: np.exp(poly(np.log(x1)))

loglog(x1,yfit(x1))
show()

Comment: It says something like the least squares fit doesn't converge

Comment: Use the [edit] link to add and properly format the code and the traceback.